# Анализ категориальных данных

Tags: pandas, библиотека

**Задача:** 
Подсчитать, сколько в колонке «Площадь кухни» уникальных категорий ?
**ВАЖНО:** Отсутствующее значение считаем как категорию !

Решение:

```
dataset['Площадь кухни'].describe()
```

Дает вывод

```
count     11821
unique      309 - # Где данная строка, вроде бы искомое значение. Однако, есть то что ВАЖНО !
top       10 м²
freq       1507
Name: Площадь кухни, dtype: object
```

```
dataset['Площадь кухни'].unique()
```

Дает вывод

```
array(['5.5 м²', '33.4 м²', nan, '17.1 м²', '15 м²', '7 м²', '12 м²',
       '10 м²', '8.7 м²', '13.5 м²', '17.3 м²', '12.18 м²', '14 м²',
       '14.6 м²', '17.6 м²', '11.2 м²', '12.8 м²', '20.5 м²', '15.45 м²',
       '9.1 м²', '8.4 м²', '5 м²', '9 м²', '11.1 м²', '10.8 м²',
       '12.1 м²', '14.7 м²', '10.28 м²', '6.9 м²', '6 м²', '8 м²',
       '16 м²', '12.2 м²', '16.1 м²', '14.9 м²', '20.6 м²', '9.3 м²',
       '9.4 м²', '13.4 м²', '12.9 м²', '13.8 м²', '3.68 м²', '6.8 м²',
       '12.04 м²', '1 м²', '6.7 м²', '9.09 м²', '8.92 м²', '10.19 м²',
       '12.4 м²', '11.17 м²', '10.1 м²', '15.9 м²', '6.5 м²', '6.1 м²',
       '9.5 м²', '13 м²', '9.6 м²', '89 м²', '18 м²', '10.2 м²', '9.2 м²',
       '8.9 м²', '15.5 м²', '20 м²', '4 м²', '31 м²', '49 м²', '105 м²',
       '69 м²', '25 м²', '37 м²', '32 м²', '11 м²', '10.02 м²',
       '14.07 м²', '10.13 м²', '8.2 м²', '20.8 м²', '8.6 м²', '8.5 м²',
       '10.5 м²', '7.5 м²', '8.12 м²', '14.2 м²', '2.1 м²', '31.2 м²',
       '11.4 м²', '14.5 м²', '3 м²', '11.52 м²', '30 м²', '15.8 м²',
       '16.29 м²', '14.01 м²', '10.65 м²', '11.32 м²', '15.6 м²',
       '10.6 м²', '7.7 м²', '24 м²', '27 м²', '9.7 м²', '11.9 м²',
       '7.4 м²', '12.12 м²', '14.89 м²', '21 м²', '8.8 м²', '9.81 м²',
       '12.37 м²', '11.8 м²', '9.78 м²', '10.3 м²', '6.6 м²', '15.1 м²',
       '9.9 м²', '22 м²', '22.5 м²', '10.4 м²', '11.5 м²', '15.3 м²',
       '11.6 м²', '22.9 м²', '19.7 м²', '31.6 м²', '19.6 м²', '18.7 м²',
       '16.2 м²', '11.3 м²', '16.9 м²', '16.5 м²', '46.8 м²', '14.8 м²',
       '24.5 м²', '14.1 м²', '29.9 м²', '32.1 м²', '12.3 м²', '21.8 м²',
       '12.6 м²', '17.5 м²', '15.2 м²', '19.8 м²', '24.2 м²', '13.1 м²',
       '19.1 м²', '9.8 м²', '16.7 м²', '19 м²', '22.6 м²', '18.9 м²',
       '18.1 м²', '20.1 м²', '18.8 м²', '19.4 м²', '13.6 м²', '8.1 м²',
       '17 м²', '13.3 м²', '19.5 м²', '21.7 м²', '14.56 м²', '14.3 м²',
       '35 м²', '14.4 м²', '7.2 м²', '13.2 м²', '10.9 м²', '11.15 м²',
       '16.3 м²', '13.7 м²', '22.3 м²', '17.2 м²', '12.7 м²', '22.8 м²',
       '15.7 м²', '15.4 м²', '37.7 м²', '17.9 м²', '26 м²', '60 м²',
       '7.8 м²', '4.8 м²', '4.4 м²', '7.1 м²', '16.4 м²', '56 м²',
       '33 м²', '23 м²', '55 м²', '38 м²', '46 м²', '10.7 м²', '19.2 м²',
       '17.8 м²', '114 м²', '52 м²', '62 м²', '87 м²', '104 м²',
       '9.83 м²', '8.26 м²', '81 м²', '34 м²', '43 м²', '85 м²', '67 м²',
       '65 м²', '12.5 м²', '44 м²', '20.2 м²', '29.5 м²', '25.2 м²',
       '86 м²', '1.6 м²', '50 м²', '58 м²', '82 м²', '28 м²', '4.7 м²',
       '7.6 м²', '27.5 м²', '19.9 м²', '25.4 м²', '22.2 м²', '71 м²',
       '6.2 м²', '21.3 м²', '18.5 м²', '16.6 м²', '4.5 м²', '29.1 м²',
       '10.86 м²', '12.34 м²', '23.9 м²', '26.6 м²', '21.6 м²', '53 м²',
       '7.3 м²', '57 м²', '12.02 м²', '115 м²', '54 м²', '10.36 м²',
       '91 м²', '73 м²', '13.9 м²', '11.28 м²', '9.96 м²', '6.46 м²',
       '7.02 м²', '7.32 м²', '6.74 м²', '6.38 м²', '5.48 м²', '9.52 м²',
       '9.42 м²', '8.98 м²', '9.06 м²', '7.24 м²', '8.88 м²', '4.3 м²',
       '4.6 м²', '16.8 м²', '6.4 м²', '20.4 м²', '26.5 м²', '5.4 м²',
       '13.57 м²', '23.91 м²', '6.3 м²', '5.8 м²', '13.16 м²', '11.58 м²',
       '4.9 м²', '8.3 м²', '7.41 м²', '5.76 м²', '6.96 м²', '76 м²',
       '29 м²', '42 м²', '51 м²', '45 м²', '14.65 м²', '14.55 м²',
       '9.36 м²', '8.67 м²', '7.74 м²', '11.16 м²', '11.08 м²', '40 м²',
       '5.2 м²', '41 м²', '11.7 м²', '5.7 м²', '14.86 м²', '10.82 м²',
       '11.42 м²', '18.3 м²', '2 м²', '13.48 м²', '20.3 м²', '21.9 м²',
       '41.7 м²', '30.2 м²', '30.7 м²', '28.8 м²', '23.2 м²'],
      dtype=object)
```

Который точно содержит в себе верный ответ!
Однако, считать в ручную количество уникальных результатов как-то НЕ Python-way.

**Отсюда вопрос**:
Каким способом воспроизвести ответ на экране о количестве уникальных категорий в указанном столбце ?

Comment: Да, похоже `describe()` пропускает `NaN` и никак это нельзя исправить. Можете ещё `df.info()` посмотреть, там показывает и с ними и без них статистику. А вообще `.unique().size` - самый нормальный способ. Ещё можно через `df.value_counts(dropna=False)` посмотреть, но как оттуда вытащить нужные данные я сходу не соображу :)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь несколько возможностей, например

1. Примените стандартную функцию `len()`:

   ```
   len(dataset['Площадь кухни'].unique())
   ```
2. Используйте NumPy `ndarray` атрибут `size`:

   ```
   dataset['Площадь кухни'].unique().size
   ```
3. Из вами примененного `dataset['Площадь кухни'].describe()` с результатом:

   > ```
   > count     11821
   > unique      309
   > top       10 м²
   > freq       1507
   > Name: Площадь кухни, dtype: object
   > ```

   т.е. из такой серии 4 значений (с индексом изображенным в левом столбце):

   - вытяните значение индекса `'unique'`

     ```
     dataset['Площадь кухни'].describe()['unique']
     ```
   - прибавите к нему `0` (`False`) или `1` (`True`) в зависимости от того,
     если в *вашем* столбце нет или находятся отсутствующее значения (атрибут `.hasnans`):

     ```
     dataset['Площадь кухни'].hasnans
     ```

   В результате в одну строку:

   ```
   dataset['Площадь кухни'].describe()['unique'] + dataset['Площадь кухни'].hasnans
   ```

   или медленнее, но красивее

   ```
   kitchens = dataset['Площадь кухни']            # ваш столбец (серия)
   description = kitchens.describe()              # серия после применения describe()  
   description['unique'] + kitchens.hasnans
   ```

   Или для того же самого используйте в последней команде обычный питонскый индекс `1` (что значит *второй* элемент серии `description`):

   ```
   kitchens = dataset['Площадь кухни']
   description = kitchens.describe()
   description[1] + kitchens.hasnans
   ```

Comment: С первыми двумя вариантами все хорошо! А вот 3-е 
>>> dataset['Площадь кухни'].describe()['unique']
и 4-е решение,
>>> dataset['Площадь кухни'].describe()[1] 
Насколько я правильно понимаю, не являются верными. Так как они не учитывают отсутствующие значения в колонке! Так ?

Comment: @SouStan, я добавил код для этого прямо в мой ответ, чтобы было все ясно.

Comment: Всех Благодарю за Решения и подсказки в рекомендациях! :-)

Comment: Благодарность здесь принято выразить [в более удобной форме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.